# Flutter splash screen doesn't update when changed

Tags: flutter, dart

I am rebranding a flutter app using Android Studio and testing on a physical android device.

I changed the /assets/images splash_screen.png to the rebranded design. however, the old splash screen continues to appear.

I have tried:

1 - flutter clean

2 - Edit/invalidate caches (both system cache and VCS)

3 - Removing app from device

4 - restarting device

my pubspec.yaml is as follows:

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#FFFFFF"
  image: assets/images/splash_screen.png
  color_dark: "#1a1a1a"
  image_dark: assets/images/splash_screen.png
  android: true
  ios: true
  android_gravity: fill
  ios_content_mode: scaleAspectfill
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need call this after every time you change the asset or configuration:

```
flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```

Comment: This did the trick.  Thank you!!